# My program crashes when calling vkCmdBindDescriptorSets

Tags: c++, vulkan

My program runs well when I open only one model file. But when I try to open multiple files (with different vulkan instance and thread), my program might crash in this place. I checked the arguments of the function, but they seemed to have no any problem. 
The GDB backtrace is here:

```
Thread 83 "VulkanRenderer" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffebfdff700 (LWP 50908)]
0x00007fffe35b7053 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-glcore.so.375.39
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffe35b7053 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-glcore.so.375.39
#1  0x00007fffe35e1a7e in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-glcore.so.375.39
#2  0x00007fffe35e3102 in ?? () from /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libnvidia-glcore.so.375.39
#3  0x00007ffff78ca4ed in VulkanCommandBuffer::SetDescriptorSet(vk::PipelineBindPoint, VulkanPipelineLayout*, unsigned int, unsigned int, VulkanDescriptorSet**, unsigned int, unsigned int*) () from
```

How can I fix this crash bug?

Comment: Are you sure all the objects you're using (command buffer, pipeline layout, descriptor set) are from the correct instance? You can't use objects created under one instance with another instance.

For that matter, is there a reason you need multiple instances? Most programs are fine with a single instance, unless they're doing two completely unrelated and independent things with Vulkan.

Comment: @Jesse Yes, I'm sure the descriptor set was created with the correct instance.
My program work fine on Windows, but when run it on Linux, it may crush.

Answer (score 0):

Are the commands being sent to the same queue or different queues. Also where is the output going? Is it the same window for both instances?

Comment: Yes, all commands are sent to the same queue. My program renders the scene to an off screen surface.